# How to get a publicly accessible url for a timeline item attachment?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I wondered how could I get a publicly accessible url for a timeline item attachment (like an image) that doesn't require authentication to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible as image attachments are private to the user: they indeed require an access token to be retrieved.

The only way you could make the image publicly available is by providing some sort of proxy that would fetch the image using a stored token and returning it to the requester.